# TypeError: string indices must be integers, not NoneType

Tags: python

Stackoverflow is cutting this part of the message everytime somehow.. Anyway: I'm trying to make a special kind of search function in python. Basically it's one that ignores higher/lower case and spaces. Also ' and " are considered equal. All works well and I'm able to open a text file and find the word "path" in it. But when I try to look for "d=\"" I get a very weird error. Apparently I'm indexing a string with a NoneType variable... But 7 lines above I'm indexing it in the exact same way and over there it works!!

Here is my code

```
import wx

class Mywin(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(Mywin, self).__init__(parent, title = title,size = (400, 200))

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.bButton = wx.Button(self.panel, -1, "Vector bestand kiezen", pos=(10, 10))
        self.bButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.bButton_clicked)

        self.sb = self.CreateStatusBar()

        self.panel.SetSizer(vbox)
        self.panel.Layout()

        self.Centre()
        self.Show()
        self.Fit()

    def bButton_clicked(self, event):
        with wx.FileDialog(self, "Open vector file", wildcard="Scalable vector graphic (*.svg)|*.svg|Drawing exchange format (*.dxf)|*.dxf", style=wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST) as fileDialog:

            if fileDialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_CANCEL:
                return     # the user changed their mind

            # Proceed loading the file chosen by the user
            self.pathname = fileDialog.GetPath()
            self.sb.SetStatusText("File was opened. Finding separated paths.")
            self.extractPaths()
        return

    def specialFind(self, sIndex, substring):
        eIndex = sIndex
        findingStart = 1
        i = int(0)
        while(i < len(substring)):
            print("i: {}".format(i))
            if(i == 0):
                print("looking for the start")
                findingStart = 1
            else:
                findingStart = 0
            if(substring[i] == "\'"):
                while(1):
                    if((self.text[eIndex] == "\'") | (self.text[eIndex] == "\"")):
                        print(self.text[eIndex])
                        eIndex = eIndex + 1
                        break
                    elif((self.text[eIndex] == " ") | (findingStart == 1)):
                        eIndex = eIndex + 1
                        if(eIndex == len(self.text)):
                            return -1
                        continue
                    else:
                        eIndex = eIndex + 1
                        i = -1
                        break
            elif((ord(substring[i]) >= 65) & (ord(substring[i]) <= 122)):
                print("Looking for the letter: {}".format(substring[i]))
                if(ord(substring[i]) <= 90):
                    sign = 1
                else:
                    sign = -1
                while(1):
                    print("{}, type: {}".format(eIndex, type(eIndex)))
                    if( ord(self.text[eIndex]) == ord(substring[i]) ): 
                    # | (ord(self.text[eIndex]) ==  ord(substring[i]) + sign * 32)):
                        print("{}:: {}".format(self.text[eIndex], eIndex))
                        eIndex = eIndex + 1
                        break
                    elif((ord(self.text[eIndex]) == ord(" ")) | (findingStart == 1)):
                        print("{} != {}".format(ord(self.text[eIndex]), ord(substring[i])))
                        eIndex = eIndex + 1
                        if(eIndex == len(self.text)):
                            print("searched whole document")
                            return -1
                        continue
                    else:
                        print("{} != {}".format(self.text[eIndex], substring[i]))
                        print("trying again")
                        eIndex = eIndex + 1
                        i = -1
                        break
            else:
                while(1):
                    if(ord(self.text[eIndex]) ==  ord(substring[i])):
                        print("{}:: {}".format(self.text[eIndex], eIndex))
                        eIndex = eIndex + 1
                        break
                    elif((ord(self.text[eIndex]) == ord(" ")) | (findingStart == 1)):
                        eIndex = eIndex + 1
                        if(eIndex == len(self.text)):
                            return -1
                        continue
                    else:
                        eIndex = eIndex + 1
                        i = -1
                        break
            i = i + 1

    def extractPaths(self):
        self.pathAmount = 0

        file = open(self.pathname, "r")
        self.text = file.read()
        self.textLength = len(self.text)

        pathIndex = 0
        dsIndex = 0
        deIndex = 0

        while(1):
            pathIndex = self.specialFind(deIndex, "<path")
            if(pathIndex == -1):
                print("No path found this time.")
                break
            dsIndex = self.specialFind(pathIndex, "d=\"")
            deIndex = self.specialFind(dsIndex, "\"")
            if((dsIndex == -1) | (deIndex == -1)):
                self.sb.SetStatusText("File is corrupted. Path tag was opened, but never properly closed.")
                break
            self.pathAmount = self.pathAmount + 1

        print("pathAmount: {}".format(self.pathAmount))

        return

print("<: {}".format(ord('<')))
# print("a: {}, A: {}".format(ord('a'), ord('A')))
# for i in range(ord('A'), ord('z') + 6):
    # print("{}".format(chr(i)))

app = wx.App() 
Mywin(None,  'Vector splitter.')
app.MainLoop()
```

And this is the file I'm opening:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="4" height="4" viewBox="-2 -2 4 4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
<title>OpenSCAD Model</title>
<path d="
M 2,-0 L -1,-1.73205 L -1,1.73205 z
" stroke="black" fill="lightgray" stroke-width="0.5"/></svg>
```

It's an SVG I'm trying to split into disconnected polygons to save to separate svg files.

This is the output the python script is giving me:

```
C:\Users\Anteino\Desktop\python svg splitter>python gui.py
<: 60
i: 0
looking for the start
<:: 0
i: 1
Looking for the letter: p
1, type: <type 'int'>
t != p
trying again
i: 0
looking for the start
<:: 21
i: 1
Looking for the letter: p
22, type: <type 'int'>
/ != p
trying again
i: 0
looking for the start
<:: 30
i: 1
Looking for the letter: p
31, type: <type 'int'>
p:: 31
i: 2
Looking for the letter: a
32, type: <type 'int'>
a:: 32
i: 3
Looking for the letter: t
33, type: <type 'int'>
t:: 33
i: 4
Looking for the letter: h
34, type: <type 'int'>
h:: 34
i: 0
looking for the start
Looking for the letter: d
None, type: <type 'NoneType'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gui.py", line 31, in bButton_clicked
    self.extractPaths()
  File "gui.py", line 119, in extractPaths
    dsIndex = self.specialFind(pathIndex, "d=\"")
  File "gui.py", line 68, in specialFind
    if( ord(self.text[eIndex]) == ord(substring[i]) ):
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not NoneType
```

I really don't get it. Any ideas?

Comment: `specialFind` returns `None` implicitly if it reaches its end. This `None` may be fed back to it in`sIndex`.

Comment: That's it! Thanks so much for opening my eyes. After a while of debugging I just get kind of blind.

Answer (score 0):

As Michael already pointed out the specialFind doesn't return an int and python doesn't warn you about the type of variable you're sending back. One of these times python's tolerant character isn't so practical huh.